# Rails serving old static css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a file `public/client/development/angular.css` that I have made changes to. When I visit `localhost:3000/client/development/angular.css` (with browser cache disabled) I get the old version of the file. I've verified that rails is giving a 200 response and not a 304. If I append a query string to the url, like `localhost:3000/client/development/angular.css?v=1`, I get the new version. So it seems like it's cached somewhere on the rails side. What is rails doing? And how can I get it to clear whatever cache it is using?

Comment: One of the main reasons you want to use the assets pipeline and not just create CSS files directly in `/public` is that rails attaches a digest to the URL that busts the client side cache.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm modifying existing code, so I'm stuck with the existing design. That said, it's not a client-side cache, it's coming from rails.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you on?  In older versions, rails would append an asset's file timestamp to the path as a query parameter such as: "client/development/angular.css?1385926153" to keep track of updated files. This would produce the changed file when adjusting the query param like you described.  Newer rails' versions utilize fingerprinting.  Try forcibly busting the cache by upping the asset version. Go to config/initializers/assets.rb and set "Rails.application.config.assets.version = '2.0'"

Comment: On rails 5.2.2. There was no asset version defined in assets.rb, so I added that line but no luck.